# Java - Listing the index of duplicate values in an int array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, exception, duplicates

I have to locate and list all duplicate index values in array.

Example:
int[] array = { 0, 7, 9, 1, 5, 8, 7, 4, 7, 3};

7 is located in three different locations at index 1, 6, and 8. How would I go about modifying my existing code in order to have outputResults.setText() show the location of the duplicate values? outputResults.setText() is JTextField if that helps.

```
String tmp1 = getNumbers.getText();
    try {
        int search = Integer.parseInt(tmp1);
        for (p = 0; p < array.length; p++) {
            if(array[p]==search) {
                b = true;
                index = p;
            }
        }   
        if(b==true)
            outputResults.setText(search + " was in the following fields of the array " + index);
         else 
            throw new NumberNotFoundException("Your number was not found.");


    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getContentPane(), "You can only search for integers.");

    } catch (NumberNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getContentPane(), ex.getMessage());
    }
```

At it's current state, it will only list the last time the duplicate number was located which would be index 8 based on my example. The list of numbers in the array is inputted by the user, and I'm not allowed to sort the values. My original guess was to create a nested loop and whenever it located an duplicated number, add p (current index it's searching) to a new array. I would then list the full array in outputResults.setText() but it gave several warnings and errors when I tried.

The full code can be found here if needed: http://pastebin.com/R7rfWAv0
And yes, the full program is a mess but it gets the job done and I was having such a headache with it. Also note, in the full program, the professor asked us to throw an exception if a duplicate value was detected as extra credit. I did it, but I commented it out to finish the original assignment so please disregard it.

Comment: I believe the answer is fairly obvious if you think about it for a bit. That is, in my opinion, the purpose of a homework. Perhaps instead of saving the index you could do something else there...

Comment: To be honest, I thought the same thing but after staring at an assignment for several hours, you tend to forgot the basics. I've been working on it for quite a while but I can't seem to get it work properly. My main concern would be to display the array of indexes in a JTextField on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `List` to record the indexs

```
List<Integer> indexs =new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (p = 0; p < array.length; p++) {
    if(array[p]==search) {
        indexs.add(p);
    }
}
if(p.length()>0){
    //print the result
}
```

Comment: We haven't gone over List yet in class but after a reading about it in orcales, it seems like it can get the job done. The only problem is that eclipse is telling me "The type List is not generic; it can not be parameterized with arguments <Integers>". I'll look further into it, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user1462300 Just use `<Integer>` is OK. `<Integers>` is invalid.see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

No need for Hash tables, lists or whatever, you can do this very easily as so:

```
int [] array = { 0, 7, 9, 1, 5, 8, 7, 4, 7, 3};
int pointer=0;
int currNumber;
while(pointer<array.length)
{   
  currNumber=array[pointer];
  for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){          
    if(currNumber==array[i] && i>pointer){
        System.out.println("Duplicate for "+currNumber +" in " +i);
        break;
    }
  }   
  pointer++;
}
```

It will print all duplicates for all the numbers in the array.

```
Duplicate for 7 in 6
Duplicate for 7 in 8
```

Obviously, you'd probably have to concatenate a string and display it at the end of the loop by calling `outputResults.setText()`

[Demo here.](http://ideone.com/Ba6tF)

Answer (score 1):

How about just two for loops?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[i] == array[j]) {
      System.out.println("Duplicate - " + array[i] + " found at index " + i + " and " + j);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats wrong! you are always evaluating the same position. E.g. array[0] == array[0]

Comment: @karlihnos Pretend array.length = 3. The loops are nested. It enters first loop at i = 0. Then enters second loop at j = 0. Then i=0, j=1; i=0, j=2. Now j=3 !< array.length, so exit second loop. First loop increments i. i=1, j=0; i=1, j=1, etc.

Comment: Taking the example from the op:  int[] array = { 0, 7, 9, 1, 5, 8, 7, 4, 7, 3}. He says: 7 is repeated at postiitons 1,6 and 8. In your code you evaluate array[0]==array[0], after j is done, it continues comparing array[1] and  j will be somewhen arrays[1], it means again array[1]=array[1]. So basically, you are comparing each number with its self

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a HashMap that used the value as the key, and a collection of indexes for the value.  As you scan the array, if the value isn't in the HashMap, add it w/ a new collection of the index.  If the value is in the array, pull the collection, add the next index and finish the iteration.

Once that's complete, iterate the HashMap, any entry who has a value with size() > 1 has duplicates.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what a HashMap is. We never went over anything related to it in class. Would you be willing to explain it a little? I'll research into it in the meantime.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html Basically, it's a hashtable but implemented using the Map Collection interface.

Answer (score 0):

As you're iterating through the array, you are overwriting any previously found index with the line `index = p;`. This line only works if there is one occurrence of the value being searched. Let `index` be a string and concat to it each time you arrive at that line, so that `index += " "+p;`. Your line:

```
 outputResults.setText(search + " was in the following fields of the array " + index);
```

will then print out all of the found indices for the value being searched.

So, there are several ways to complete your solution (some naive and some optimal) with that being said; you should think through what you're trying to achieve and figure out what each line is doing in your code (debug) when you have an issue.

Comment: Oh wow, cannot believe I forgot about +=. That actually worked perfectly! And yea, I know there's several ways to achieve the results I wanted, but like I mentioned before, when you work on something for a long period of time, you tend to forget the basics and simple methods of doing things. Thank you so much!

Comment: If this helped solve your issue please mark it as accepted. The tick mark under the number of up votes.